# scikit learn: 5 fold cross validation & train test split

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am wondering when I do train test split (20% test, 80% 80%) and then I apply 5 fold cross validation does that mean all data has been in the test set once? or is it randomly choosed each time that, in each fold the same events were possibly included in the test more than once and some possibly were never included in test set?

```
#20% of the data will be used as test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=seed) 

cv_results= cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will all data have been in the test set once? Yes, at least within the data that you pass to your cross validation method. For example:

```
X = np.arange(10)
y = np.concatenate((np.ones(5), np.zeros(5)))
X
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
y
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2, random_state=42)
X_train
array([5, 0, 7, 2, 9, 4, 3, 6])
X_test
array([8, 1])
kf = Kfold(n_splits=5)
for train, test in kf.split(X_train):
    print(train, test)
[2 3 4 5 6 7] [0 1]
[0 1 4 5 6 7] [2 3]
[0 1 2 3 6 7] [4 5]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 7] [6]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6] [7]
```

As you can see the indices for the test set run from 0 to 7 meaning that all 8 values in `X_train` will have appeared in the cross validation test once. This pattern would persist regardless of your sample size.

The size of the splits created by the cross validation [`split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold.split) method are determined by the ratio of your data to the number of splits you choose. For example if I had set `KFold(n_splits=8)` (the same size as my `X_train` array) the test set for each split would comprise a single data point.

Comment: Thank you so much!! One quick question if you could help me to understand, in your example, the test size from test_train split is 0.2. so after the 5 fold, why are two of them not having the test size equal to 0.2 ? [0 1 2 3 4 5 7] [6]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6] [7] .... why wont it be something like  [0 1 2 3 4 5 ] [6 7] &  [0  2 3 4 5 6] [7 1]

Comment: oh wait ignore my question i think i get it now thank you so much :)

Comment: The values of x_test will never make it into your cross val as you are only passing x_train.

Comment: Thank you so much! one last question...so i dont really need to do tra/ test split if I am doing k fold cross validation right?

Comment: I've seen it done both ways and hotly debated. I was trained to have a test set that is never trained on either by cross validation or otherwise.

Comment: That makes sense thank you so much I really appricate